# Angular 6+ ngcc failed to run on ngx-monaco-editor

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ngx-monaco-editor

Using NPM Library [ngx-monaco-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor) to setup Editor

As soon as I install the library get the following error in the browser :

`ngcc failed to run on ngx-monaco-editor@9.0.0.`

Code Tried in [Stackblitz Proj](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygwqgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution?